# For loop append div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I wanted to ask the loop currently in my code I am doing this manually its working manually

```
          $( '<div id="demo1" > <span class="value"></span> </div><br> Loading' ).appendTo( $('.test')[0] );         
  $( '<div id="demo2"> <span class="value"></span> </div><br> Loading' ).appendTo( $('.test')[1] );
```

But I am trying to do it buy function until div id demo10
this is what I tried I am trying to implement in for loop but its not working showing blank only can anyone guide me I am new to jquery I will really appreciate any advice. Thank you

```
  function newdiv()
{
    var j,i;
     for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++,j=i+1) {

      $( '<div id="demo-"'+j+'"' +' > <span class="value"></span> </div><br> Loading' ).appendTo( $('.test')[i] );         

     }

}
```

Comment: so basically, you have a div which has a class called test, so you need to append new div by running the function.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157895/create-multiple-divs-inside-a-containing-div

Comment: @rod what is the sequence of j in the loop ?

Comment: Yes I have  a class called test  and  need to append new div by running the function

Comment: @rod Please check the answer

Comment: @rod is your code being called in document ready?  `$(function() { newdiv(); }`

Comment: You have an extra `"` - `id="demo-"'+j+'"' +' ` should be `id="demo-'+j+'"' +' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below code will solve the issue

Detail Description

1. So when the dom loads we need to execute the function, so we invoked the function using **newdiv()**
2. Now the function gets executed, so each time the i value will get incremented and it will add the new element to the div which is already in html. We select it through class name which is test.
3. So it will append new elements to the **test** div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function newdiv() {
    var j, i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++, j = i + 1) {
     var appendElement = `<div id='demo-${i}'>
      <span class='value'></span>
     </div>
     <br>
     Loading`;
    $('.test').append(appendElement)
    }

  }

  newdiv();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this code, It is giving the same output as well.

```js
var i=0;
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
if(i==1)
$("#demo").after('<div id="demo1" > <span class="value"></span> </div><br> Loading');
else{
var div = parseInt(i)-1;
$("#demo"+div).after('<div id="demo'+parseInt(i)+'" > <span class="value"></span> </div><br> Loading');
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" ></div>
```

Comment: `parseInt(int)` ?

Comment: It is javascript function that converts string into int. If you will not use this , It will give the same output :p

Comment: "converts string into int" - then why are you using it *convert **int** into int* ?  `for (i = 1..` does not create a "string" loop variable.